# Using regular expression to catch phrases in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to use the regular expression in Python to catch a phrase in a question sentence like:

> Who created Lord of the Rings?

**And all I want to catch is the phrase after the phrase "Who created", which in this case is the "Lord of the Rings". And the phrase could be anything, e.g "Microsoft" etc.** I tried with the following python code:

```
matchObj = re.match(r'Whocreated(\w+)'+re.escape('?')+r'?', query, re.I|re.X)
```

and also this:

```
matchObj = re.match(r'Who created (\w+)'+re.escape('?')+r'?', query, re.I|re.X)
```

And I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "infobox_MQL.py", line 233, in 
>      main()
>    File "infobox_MQL.py", line 222, in main
>      print matchObj.group()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I can use hard coding to extract the phrase I want for sure, but I just wonder if there is a nice way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oV6aF8/1) is a nice tool, you should give it a try, it will show you why your regexp doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> regex = re.compile("Who created (.*?)\?", re.I)
>>> regex.search("Who created Lord of the Rings?").groups()[0]
'Lord of the Rings'
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I haven't made my question clear, I was having trouble mainly because I want to consider the case that the question mark could either exist or not. But don't worry, I am not going to look for that kind of trouble for my self now.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use `in` which should perform faster than regex:

```
string = "Lord of the Rings"
if string in matchObj:
    print string
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't made my question clear enough, please see the bold line in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> query = 'Who created Lord of the Rings?'
>>> matchobj = re.search('Lord of the Rings', query)
>>> matchobj.group()
'Lord of the Rings'
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't made my question clear enough, please see the bold line in the question above.